# iterating a vector how to check at which position I am?

Tags: c++, vector, iteration

Example:

```
for (vector<string>::reverse_iterator it = myV.rbegin(); it != myV.rend(); ++it)
{
  cout << "current value is: " << *it << ", and current position is: " << /*  */ << endl;
}
```

I know I could check how many items there are in the vector, make a counter, and so on. But I wonder if there is a more direct way of checking current index without asserting that I got the length of the vector right.

Comment: `std::distance(myV.rbegin(), it)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vector Iterators support [difference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/reverse_iterator/operator-/) you can subtract you current iterator it from rbegin.

---

*EDIT*

As noted in a comment not all iterators support operator- so std::distance would have to be used.  However I would not recommend this as std::distance will cause a liner time performance cost for iterators that are not random access while if you use `it - begin()` the compiler will tell you that won't work and then you can use distance if you must.

Comment: Do the iterators remember their position with respect to the begin(), or is the std::distance called to compute the distance?

Comment: they are requried to have a globally overloaded operator for difference_type operator-(riter,riter) the way its implemented in you library may differ. Some implantation use a pointer for a random access iterator.

Comment: What happens if I have a vector of 1e09 elements and call std::distance every time? Is it not better in that case to rely on the [] operator and write a standard for loop?

Comment: with a random access iterator its assured to be a constant time operation for all other iterators its linear time.

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean. So, if I use std::distance each time, instead of writing a classical for loop and using [], I will have this much surplus "-" operations to compute the iterator position: (const time for the std::distance of a std::vector * vector size) . If I have huge vectors, that's a lot of differences that I can live without..

Comment: With your current phrasing, you make it sound like all types of iterator support subtraction. This is not correct.

Comment: @juanchopanza No that's now what I mean, that's just my bad English... :) I'm talking about writing this if I know that I'll be using a vector. In this case I have [] at my disposal, and there's no need for iterators, whose sole purpose is to be able to write same algorithm code for different container types.

Comment: @tomislav-maric the comment was indented for this answer, not your question, which is clear enough :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza :)) Now I'm really embarrassed.

Comment: @juanchopanza fixed as per your comment

Answer (score 1):

Subtract `std::vector<T>::begin()` (or `rbegin()` in your case) from the current iterator.  Here's a small example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> x;
    x.push_back(1);
    x.push_back(1);
    x.push_back(3);

    std::cout << "Elements: " << x.end() - x.begin();
    std::cout << "R-Elements: " << x.rend() - x.rbegin();
    return 0;    
}
```

As pointed out in a really great comment above, `std::distance` may be an even better choice.  `std::distance` supports random access iterators in constant time, but also supports other categories of iterators in linear time.

Answer (score 1):

Iterators are used to allow generic algorithms to be written that invariant to a choice of a container. I've read in the [STL Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379260) that this is great, but may lead to performance drop because sometimes the member functions of a container are optimized for the container and will run faster than generic code that relies on iterators. In this case, if you are dealing with a large vector, you will be calling the std::distance, which although constant is not necessary. If you know that you will be using oly vector for this algorithm, you may recognize that it supports the direct access operator "[]" and write something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main ()
{


    vector<int> myV;


    for (int I = 0; I < 100; ++I)
    {
        myV.push_back(I); 
    }


    for (int I = 0; I < myV.size(); ++I)
    {
        cout << "current value is: " << myV[I] 
            << ", and current position is: " << I << endl;
    }


    return 0; 
}
```

In case you are interested in speed, you can always try the different answers proposed here and measure the execution time. It will depend on the vector size probably.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a counter:

```
for (vector<string>::reverse_iterator it = myV.rbegin(), 
                                 int pos = myV.size; 
     it != myV.rend(), 
         --pos; 
     ++it)
{
    cout << "current value is: " << *it << ", and current position is: " << pos << endl;
}
```

Comment: A lot of extra overhead for something that is trivially calculated from random access iterators (which `vector` iterators are).  For, other types of iterators, will reduce the algorithmic complexity at a cost of additional code maintenance.

Comment: The overhead is ginormous, yes, and the algorithmic complexity is off the charts, I agree. But I do actually like the iterator calculation better.

Comment: :D  Just pointing out that for random access iterators this is unnecessary, and this question was specifically about `std::vector`.  However, for large containers that are _not_ random access (large `map`s, `set`s, `list`s, etc.) this is actually a good approach, but it has to be weighed against the expected size of the container.

Comment: I agree with all that except that it's "A lot of overhead". It's just overhead. But doing the iterator calculation is still better.